# C++ - Removing element by value of custom data type vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to delete vector element by value for custom data type vector. It works fine If I use the simple data type like `int` etc instead of `hello` data type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class hello
{

public:
    hello() {
        x = false;
    }
    bool x;
};

int main() {

   hello f1;
   hello f2;
   hello f3;

   std::vector <hello> vector_t;

   vector_t.push_back(f1);
   vector_t.push_back(f2);
   vector_t.push_back(f3);

   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vector_t.size(); i++)
       {
       if (vector_t[i].x)
       {
            vector_t.erase(std::remove(vector_t.begin(), vector_t.end(), i), vector_t.end());
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It shows an error:

> binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'hello' (or there is no acceptable conversion) vector_test

Comment: Take a look here: `std::remove(vector_t.begin(), vector_t.end(), i)`. The last argument needs to be `hello` not `unsigned int`.

Comment: Third param `i` of `remove` needs to be of type `hello`

Comment: @DimChtz This gives the following error: `'hello': illegal use of this type as an expression vector_test`

Comment: what do you want to acheive? delete a range of elements? or a single element?

Comment: @SamerTufail it is very clear in the heading: to remove the vector elements by value.

Comment: It's a reasonable question, since your `i` looks like a _position_ (it iterates over the vector indices) rather than a value (it isn't comparable or convertible to a `hello`).

Comment: @Zeeshan Hayat Use this code : `vector_t.erase(vector_t.begin() + i);`

Comment: @ZeeshanHayat it is from the heading but from your code it looks like you are trying to delete a range of elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to rather use [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) where the `.x` member is true.

```
vector_t.erase(std::remove_if(vector_t.begin(), vector_t.end(), [](const hello &h) { return h.x; }), vector_t.end());
```

The `for` loop and `if` condition aren't necessary, they're not needed this way.

Comment: This renders the `if(vector_t[i].x)` redundant.

Comment: @SamerTufail yes, this replaces the whole loop

Comment: Yea I know but just thought you would let the OP know, it would do that. (:

Comment: @acraig5075 very elegant solution, Thanks :)

Comment: Anybody can explain me why using only `remove-if` is not adequate to delete the element by value. `vector_t.erase(...,vector_t.end())` will not erase all the elements until the end of the vector whatever their value ?

Comment: @acraig5075, thanks, the next time i would read better the documentation that confirm how remove_if works

Answer (score 3):

`remove` tries to find all elements that *compare equal* to whatever you passed to it. If you do not tell the compiler how to compare `hello` objects with the integer `i` value, it cannot do that.

What you probably wanted to do was to just remove the i-th element of the vector if it satisfies your criterion:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vector_t.size(); i++)
{
    if (vector_t[i].x)
    {
        vector_t.erase(vector_t.begin() + i);
        --i; // The next element is now at position i, don't forget it!
    }
}
```

The most idiomatic way would be using `std::remove_if` as shown in acgraig5075's answer.

Answer (score 3):

> It shows an error:
>
> `binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type
>   'hello' (or there is no acceptable conversion) vector_test`

You can provide the obviously missing operator `==` for your class which will solve the issue:

```
bool operator==(hello const &h)
{
    return this->x == h.x;
}
```

Your remove/erase should look like this though:

```
vector_t.erase(std::remove(vector_t.begin(), vector_t.end(), vector_t[i]), vector_t.end());
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/E3aV76

Comment: == operator overloading requires two arguments, isn't?

Comment: @ZeeshanHayat Not always. This one is part of your class so it only needs another class as argument. Check the demo.